# Drawing in Java (simulator)

Tags: java, draw, simulation, lines

**Can you help me how can i program this:**

I have a jPanel as a graphic zone, I want to generate a line from drawing, I have a random distance, and a random alpha. 
The problem is whene the first point of line is in this jPanel and the second is out from this jPanel. 
I want to draw the rested line, from the other part, this image explain what i want to do:

[Simulation example](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ggnUv6mg9e0/U3SsMahrOFI/AAAAAAAAAdE/IaoeVaKR4zI/w918-h516-no/15-05-2014+13-38-49.jpg)

The Tests are:

```
if(y1<0){
        tmp_x=x1;
        tmp_y=y1;
        x1= (x1-(Math.abs(y1)*(x1-x))/(Math.abs(y-y1)));
        y1=0;
        g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        System.out.println("(x,y);(x1,y1): ("+x+","+y+");"+"("+x1+","+y1+")");
        x=x1;
        y=jPanel1.getHeight();
        x1=tmp_x;
        y1=jPanel1.getHeight()-Math.abs(tmp_y);
    }
if(y1>jPanel1.getHeight()){
        tmp_x=x1;
        tmp_y=y1;
        x1=x1-(Math.abs(Math.abs(y1-y)-Math.abs(y1-jPanel1.getHeight())))*(x1-x)/(Math.abs(y1-y));
        y1=jPanel1.getHeight();
        g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        System.out.println("(x,y);(x1,y1): ("+x+","+y+");"+"("+x1+","+y1+")");
        x=x1;
        y=0;
        x1=tmp_x;
        y1=tmp_y-jPanel1.getHeight();
    }

   if(x1<0){
        tmp_x=x1;
        tmp_y=y1;
        y1= (y1-(Math.abs(x1)*(y1-y))/(Math.abs(x-x1)));
        x1=0;
        g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        System.out.println("(x,y);(x1,y1): ("+x+","+y+");"+"("+x1+","+y1+")");
        y=y1;
        x=jPanel1.getWidth();
        y1=tmp_y;
        x1=jPanel1.getWidth()-Math.abs(tmp_x);
    }

   if(x1>jPanel1.getWidth()){
        tmp_x=x1;
        tmp_y=y1;
        y1=y1-(Math.abs(Math.abs(x1-x)-Math.abs(x1-jPanel1.getWidth())))*(y1-y)/(Math.abs(x1-x));
        x1=jPanel1.getWidth();
        g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);
        System.out.println("(x,y);(x1,y1): ("+x+","+y+");"+"("+x1+","+y1+")");
        y=y1;
        x=0;
        y1=tmp_y;
        x1=tmp_x-jPanel1.getWidth();

    }
```

**Where is the problem?**

Comment: A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be tremendously helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

With a Graphic object you can draw a line that end (or start) outside the real size of the canvas. The Graphics object have a theoretical infinite surface and so you can draw any where.

For example, you can do:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frm = new JFrame();

        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frm.setSize(200, 200);

        frm.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p = new Main();

        frm.add(p);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        // Start outside
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, -100, 100, 100);

        // End outside
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 0, 300);

        // Start and end outside
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(-100, 100, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Also note that your code have many errors, for example you are checking only if one axis is outside, but both can be outside at the same time. What happend if all are outside, for example (-100, -100) -> (-200, -200)?

You can still do it, but you need more checks. Form example:

- Check if both points (extremes of the segment) are insede the bounds. Then draw normally.
- Check if one is inside and the other not. Then check the intersection of the boundaries with the segment and use that point.
- Check if both are outside. Then you must calculate the intersection again but get in mind that you can get 0, 1 or 2 points of intersection (if are totally outside=0, if only touch a corner=1 and if it cross the entery square=2).